# Need to know if a value contain 3 letters and 3 numbers

Tags: python, pandas, filter, dataset

I am working with car plate data from my country and I need to check if there is a plate misspelled. The current and correct form is with three letters and three numbers (AAA000), but I saw values like one letter or all numbers. So far I am only capable to know if it is all numbers or letters. Sorry I have no code to share, I'm still too noob.

[image]

Comment: Regex -- `re.match(r"[A-Z]{3}\d{3}", "AAA000")`

Comment: Could it be  OOO003 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supose plate is a list, you can do it with regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> plates = ['000003', 'TPU553', 'TPU374', 'SVM978']
>>> list(filter(lambda x : re.match(r'\D{3}\d{3}',x),plates))
['TPU553', 'TPU374', 'SVM978']
```

Comment: `[A-Z]{3}` would be better that `\D{3}` as `\D` matches much more than just letters

Comment: also note that the pattern will match ABC123#.

Answer (score 1):

This function must resolve your problem:

```
df["Placa"].apply(lambda x: True if x[:3].isalpha() and x[3:].isdigit() and len(x) == 6 else False)
```

Comment: `isalpha`  is true for lower case letters and some unicode characters.  Probably not what the OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

This is my take on your question. Made a function that checks if the 3 first characters are letter and so on with the next 3 characters.

```
def checkcarplate(carplate):
    for i in range(len(carplate)):
        if i<3:
            if not carplate[i].isalpha():
                print('error')
                break
        elif i>2:
            if not carplate[i].isdigit():
                print('error')
                break
            elif i==len(carplate)-1:
                print('ok')    
carplate="A1C123"
checkcarplate(carplate)
carplate="ABC123"
checkcarplate(carplate)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You need to check the length of the plate.  If it's shorter than or equal to 3 (e.g. "AB") it will print nothing.  If it is longer than 6, for example "ABC12345" it will print "OK".
Instead of "elif i>2:"  I would suggest "else:"  - the "if" already means that it is 3 or more.
See also William's comments to other answers.